# Karma meter in Python 3 (Text based game)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to create a simple text game in Python 3. No special modules or anything, im totally new to python. Its a adventure game where the choices you make impact the story.

I need some help with my "karma meter" and how i might do it.
Im thinking that the easiest way to do it is to have a variable that is in this case for the main characters beloved wife, called "belovedMeter". And based on the answer given it lovers the bar from 50 to maybe 30 or something like that.

so example is that answer 3 would give minus 20 points to the meter. The question is just how do i accomplish that? When i use input it registers my answer as a "string" and i dont know if that matters or not.

I need some tips on how to do this efficient. I am going to repeat this alot of times in my code.

Im quite new to programming so you know.
here is my first "thought" on the code itself:

```
while answer1 != "1" and answer1 != "2" and answer1 != "3": #Check if a valid answer is given.
print("1: yo")
print("2: hey")
print("3: Stfu!!")
answer1 = input("Please choose an answer (pick 1-3)")

belovedMeter = 50
```

Comment: Cast the answer to an `int` - `answer1 = int(input("Please choose an answer (pick 1-3)"))` - One thing though - you will have to handle answers given by users that cannot be casted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code:

```
answer1 = "" # You need to set your variable first

while answer1 not in ["1","2","3"]: # Shortened version of your if-statement 
    print("1: yo")
    print("2: hey")
    print("3: Stfu!!")
    answer1 = input("Please choose an answer (pick 1-3)")

# An easy method to find the point(s) without if-statement:
points = {"1": 50, "2": 30, "3": -20} 

belovedMeter = 50 + points[answer1]

print("Your current belovedMeter:", belovedMeter)
```

Output:

```
1: yo
2: hey
3: Stfu!!
Please choose an answer (pick 1-3)1
Your belovedMeter: 100
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look up if/else statements. They are kind of crucial towards programming.

```
answer = int(input(""))
belovedMeter=50
if answer == 3:
    belovedMeter=-20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
belovedMeter = 50

while answer1 != "1" and answer1 != "2" and answer1 != "3": #Check if a valid answer is given.
    print("1: yo")
    print("2: hey")
    print("3: Stfu!!")
    answer1 = input("Please choose an answer (pick 1-3)")
if answer1 == "1":
    belovedMeter = belovedMeter + 10    # Add 10 to the belovedMeter
if answer1 == "2":
    belovedMeter = belovedMeter + 20    # Add 20 to the belovedMeter
if answer1 == "3":
    belovedMeter = belovedMeter - 20    # Remove 20 from the belovedMeter
```

The fact that the answer is saved as a string does not really matter. It just means that is it a character chain. However, if you want to save it as a number, you can do this:

```
answer1 = int(input("Please choose an answer (pick 1-3)"))
```

The `int` function transforms a string in a number (if it can be transformed)
Also, notice the indentation after the `while` and the `if`. The indentation is necessary for the computer to understand which part of the code is in which section (for instance, the 4 lines after the `while` are considered WITHIN the while and everything else, OUTSIDE the `while`)

Then, the `if` statements are used to check if something is True or if it is False. If it is True, the indented lines below it will run on the program. And if it is False, the indented lines won't run.
And as far as the belovedMeter is concerned, in order to change it's value you just have to do this:

```
belovedMeter = belovedMeter + x
```

or

```
belovedMeter += x    # Same thing as above.
```

where x is and integer you want to add or substract to the belovedMeter

Comment: Im aware of the indentation and will think of that in my future code that i submit here to be more clear. But i am really thankful for your submissions and i think you guys came up with a perfect solution to my problem. Thanks! If i have any questions i will post them here.